# How to tick "choose paper source by pdf page size" iText7?

Tags: java, pdf, itext7

I am trying to check "Choose paper source by pdf page size" in print options via iText7, for my project requirement which is generating pdf. But library the I am using, I am not able to find the desired thing.

```
public static void createPdf_PageType(String baseUri, String[] src, String dest, PageSize pageSize, boolean rotate) throws IOException {

    ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
    properties.setBaseUri(baseUri);
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);

    PdfViewerPreferences preferences = new PdfViewerPreferences();
    preferences.setPrintScaling(PdfViewerPreferencesConstants.NONE);
    pdf.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(preferences);

    PdfMerger merger = new PdfMerger(pdf);
    log.info("Generating PDF");
    for (String html : src) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfDocument temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(baos));
        if(rotate) {
        temp.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize.rotate()); /** Page Size and Orientation */
        } else {
            temp.setDefaultPageSize(pageSize); /** Page Size and Orientation */
        }

        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(html, temp, properties);
        temp = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())));
        merger.merge(temp, 1, temp.getNumberOfPages());
        temp.close();
    }
  //  pdf.getCatalog().setViewerPreferences(new PdfViewerPreferences().setPrintScaling(PdfViewerPreferences.PdfViewerPreferencesConstants.NONE));
    pdf.close();
    log.info("PDF Generated");

}
```

I just want to tick checkbox of in print option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set below property for `PdfViewerPreferences`, gave expected output

```
PdfViewerPreferences preferences = new PdfViewerPreferences();
preferences.setPickTrayByPDFSize(true);
```

`iText7` provides wide range of utility methods, only proper examples and documentattion are not available.